# TaskDialog shows Chinese text instead of en-us

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi

We recently updated an internal tool to use a vendor's online tool instead of our previous home-brewed functionality. One task in this update is redirecting our users to the website when they click the button that used to do the operation.

I'd like to embed a hyperlink right on the messagebox, because typing a URL is very 1994; but MsgBox can't do that. I've been told that TaskDialog does, but it shows a bunch of chinese characters instead of the text I've entered.

I don't speak chinese, and I didn't know I had the language installed. Regardless, this dialog needs to show the english text I entered.

Please help.

Here's what I expect (roughly):
[image: msgbox dialog]

and here's what I get instead:
[image: Chinese Taskdialog]

Here's the code I used to generate the above:

```
Public Class Form1
    '[DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,  EntryPoint="TaskDialog")]
    'Static extern int TaskDialog(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hInstance, String pszWindowTitle,
    'String pszMainInstruction, String pszContent, int dwCommonButtons, IntPtr pszIcon, out int pnButton);
    Declare Function TaskDialog Lib "comctl32" Alias "TaskDialog" (
        hWndParent As IntPtr _
        , hInstance As IntPtr _
        , pszWindowTitle As String _
        , pszMainInstruction As String _
        , pszContent As String _
        , dwCommonButtons As Integer _
        , pszIcon As IntPtr _
        , ByRef pnButton As Integer) _
        As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim b As Integer = 0
        Dim r As Integer = -3

        MsgBox("Use x to process accounts" & vbCrLf &
                "Please visit http://x.u.org:8080/.")
        r = TaskDialog(Me.Handle, IntPtr.Zero,
                       "Account Processing through x",
                       "Use x to process accounts",
                       "Please visit <a href='http://x.u.org:8080/'>http://x.u.org:8080/</a>.",
                       1, UInt16.MaxValue, b)

        MsgBox(String.Format("b:|{0}|; r:|{1}|", b, r))

    End Sub
End Class
```

The final debug box shows "b:|1|; r:|0|".

Comment: You can try adding Unicode modifier between Declare and Function in the declaration to make sure it is using the expected character set.

Comment: @RyanRoos : I didn't even know that existed. You definitely should write that in an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you've converted the native .NET `DllImport` declaration into an outdated `Declare Function` declaration from the VB6 era. Normally this is fine as long as the arguments are correct, however the `DllImport` declaration is preferred to be fully compatible with .NET Platform Invocation.

In this case, the `TaskDialog` function expects Unicode (UTF-16) strings (this is indicated by the **W** in `PCWSTR`, which stands for *Wide* as in *Wide Char*). The `Declare Function` statement doesn't have a way of specifying the char set to be used, so it likely defaults to ANSI - a single byte char set.

The `TaskDialog` function expects every char to be **two bytes** long, but the string that it receives only uses one byte per character, making the function interpret every other character as part of the previous one. This results in a rather high char code, which happens to map to chinese characters in the UTF-16 character table.

If you look at the blue title of the dialog you can see that it displays only about half as many characters as your actual string ("Use x to process accounts").

The solution to this is to use a `DllImport` declaration in VB.NET as well, allowing you to specify `CharSet.Unicode`:

```
<DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Shared Function TaskDialog( _
    hWndParent As IntPtr _
    , hInstance As IntPtr _
    , pszWindowTitle As String _
    , pszMainInstruction As String _
    , pszContent As String _
    , dwCommonButtons As Integer _
    , pszIcon As IntPtr _
    , ByRef pnButton As Integer) _
    As Integer
End Function
```